# Writing a bar on top of a number

Tags: support, mathjax, editing

I want to write a question in which I have a bar on top of a number or letter to represent a recurring digit. however, I can't find any options to write the particular digit, even when I search the [help center](https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) for Latex, which is supposed to be used to edit any math statements. What will I use to write it ?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `$\overline{5}$`$=\overline{5}$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts thanks !

Comment: Corresponds to `\underline`

Comment: @DavidRoberts, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5700/writing-a-bar-on-top-of-a-number#comment28806_5700), in case it's of interest, you can fix the poor spacing with a spurious atom: `$\overline{5}$`${}= \overline{5}$ `\`$\overline{5}$\` ${}= \overline{5}$`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To give the question an answer so it can be accepted: you can use `$\overline{...}$` to get a bar over any letter or digit or group thereof.

Comment: Alrernatively, `$\bar{5}$` $\bar{5}$

Comment: @TheAmplitwist, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/28808), good point! Let's put them side by side to see the subtle difference: $\overline5\bar5$ `\overline5\bar5`. It's less subtle when overlining groups: $\overline5\overline6\overline{56}\bar5\bar6\bar{56}$ `\overline5\overline6\overline{56}\bar{56}\bar5\bar6`. (I don't see a rendering difference between `\overline5\overline6` and `\overline{56}`, though the widths probably differ slightly.  I include `\bar{56}` for parallelism, but, of course, it is almost certainly not what is desired.)

Comment: [Re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5700/writing-a-bar-on-top-of-a-number#comment28811_5701), oops, I somehow switched `\bar{56}` and `\bar5\bar6` between the actual code and the quoted code.  They look like $\bar{56}$ `\bar{56}` vs. $\bar5\bar6$ `\bar5\bar6`.